# Sinch null pointer issue

Tags: java, android, sinch

Getting this error in logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'boolean
>   com.demo.SinchService$SinchServiceInterface.isStarted()' on a null
>   object reference
>               at com.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)

My Code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements SinchService.StartFailedListener, View.OnClickListener{

SharedPreferences pref;
String ses_username,ses_email,ses_mobile;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        pref= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.demo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
        ses_username=pref.getString("userName", null);
        ses_email=pref.getString("userEmail", null);
        ses_mobile=pref.getString("userMobile", null);


        if(ses_username !=null && ses_email !=null && ses_mobile !=null)
        {
            if (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted()) {
                String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);
                getSinchServiceInterface().registerPushNotification(regId.getBytes());
                getSinchServiceInterface().startClient(ses_mobile + "-" + ses_username.toLowerCase());
            }
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Workshop_Search.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onStartFailed(SinchError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStarted() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problematic line:

```
if (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted()) {
```

`getSinchServiceInterface` returns `null` for some reason, therefore it does not have the `isStarted` method, leading to the exception. You should either fix `getSinhServiceInterface`, or, if it is correct that it might return `null`, the modify the `if`:

```
if ((getSinchServiceInterface() == null) || (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted())) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is returning a null reference:

```
 getSinchServiceInterface()
```

Can you post the code of the above method if its a method you've made?

If its a Sinch Library method, then see why its returning a null.